# Удаление тех строк в датафрейме, которые есть в другом датарейме. PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

Проблема следующая: есть два датафрейма, в одном около 1050000 строк, в другом 470000. Все те строки, из которых состоит меньший датафрейм, есть в первом. Как мне удалить из первого датафрейма всё то, что есть во втором?
Есть столбец DateTime, который включает в себя и дату, и время, то есть любая строка уникальна, Я пытаюсь опираться как-то на него, но вылезает либо ошибка, либо не то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто надо сделать правильный `join` между датафреймами - в данном случае - [left anti join](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/#pyspark-left-anti-join):

```py
df1.join(df2, ["DateTime"],"leftanti")
```